# In Unicode, is these a way to superimpose a character over another?

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a joining character that works a bit like `overset` in LaTeX. It also works a bit like the [many combining Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges), but I would like it to work for any alphabetic letter. For example, I'd like to put a small capital A over an e.

Best I could find was this esoteric Unicode block called [Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Supplement), but that doesn't define every letter in the alphabet.

Is there no joining character which puts one symbol over the other?

[image: example combining characters]

Comment: Accord to [FAQ: Characters and Combining Marks](https://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) it would appear not :/

Comment: I find this kind of surprising. I know, for instance, the fraction slash ⁄ (U+2044) allows fonts to render left and right context above respectively below. Would make sense to have a sub- and super- modifier in the same way.

Comment: Do you wish to superimpose them on the screen or on the printer?  If on the screen, when looking at the file in an editor, a browser or something like a pdf document?  Some techniques will work on some browsers, etc but not on others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

As the Wikipedia page points out, there are a variety of combining characters but this isn’t what you’re looking for. Combining characters always define a visible glyph (or none in some cases) which is superimposed upon the preceding character(s).

You could possibly achieve a lot with the characters and combining characters that exist, but Unicode generally isn’t about layout which sounds more like what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using HTML and CSS.

[image: play symbols with html and css]

The left and right characters don't exist in Unicode table. (I couldn't find them).

So I created them using following HTML code:

```html
<span>
    <span style="position:relative; right:-12px; top:-2px;">&#x2503;</span>
    &#x2BC7;
</span>
<span>&#x2BC7;</span>
<span>&#x2BC8;</span>
<span>
    &#x2BC8;
    <span style="position:relative; left:-12px; top:-2px;">&#x2503;</span>
</span>
```